# Window function with where condition (conditional row_number())

Tags: sql, oracle, row-number

I have the below clause in a select statement

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
    PARTITION BY pc
    ORDER BY
        a DESC, b DESC
) r
```

How can I apply that function only to the rows which fulfill a certain condition but without filtering the selection at the end in a where clause? .

Sample data:

| PC | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| pc1 | a1 | b1 |
| pc1 | a2 | b2 |
| pc1 | a3 | b3 |

Desired output (the condition in this case would be where a2!='a2'):

| PC | A | B | R |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| pc1 | a1 | b1 | 1 |
| pc1 | a2 | b2 | null |
| pc1 | a3 | b3 | 2 |

EDIT: I've tried the below, but it does not start from 1 but from the whole rownum count.

```
CASE
    WHEN condition THEN
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
            PARTITION BY pc
            ORDER BY
                a, b
        )
END r1
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use row_number() within a "case when" statement with a second case statement in the "partition by" as below:

```
(Case condition when true then ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
    PARTITION BY (case condition when true then pc end)
    ORDER BY
        a DESC, b DESC
) 
end)r
```

Example:

```
 create table sampledata(PC varchar(10),    A varchar(10),  B varchar(10));
 insert into sampledata values('pc1',   'a1',   'b1');
 insert into sampledata values('pc1',   'a2',   'b2');
 insert into sampledata values('pc1',   'a3',   'b3');
```

Query:

```
 select *,(Case when A<>'a2'  then ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
     PARTITION BY (case when A<>'a2' then pc end)
     ORDER BY   a , b DESC
 ) 
 end)r
 from sampledata order by a, b desc
```

Output:

| pc | a | b | r |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| pc1 | a1 | b1 | 1 |
| pc1 | a2 | b2 | null |
| pc1 | a3 | b3 | 2 |

*db<fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=42a294b5b55adca57a1d9f8ebc2f4da6)*

If condition is A<>'a1' then

Query:

```
 select *,(Case when A<>'a1'  then ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
     PARTITION BY (case when A<>'a1' then pc end)
     ORDER BY   a , b DESC
 ) 
 end)r
 from sampledata order by a, b desc
```

Output:

| pc | a | b | r |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| pc1 | a1 | b1 | null |
| pc1 | a2 | b2 | 1 |
| pc1 | a3 | b3 | 2 |

*db<fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=9a1d8888fb2c381b3b8b22fe3aee5410)*

Comment: Instead of 1,null,2 it's returning 1,null,3. Does it server your purpose?

Comment: No, unfortunately I need 1, null, 2. That's why I was struggling.

Comment: I have revised my answer. Hope it's what you are looking for.

Comment: @jeiv Please let me know if you have any other observations.

Comment: The code in the first block, at the beginning of your answer, is still wrong. When you worked on test cases, you found the right answer: you must use the `case` expression twice, not just once. It would be better to make that correction in the first code block as well.

Comment: @mathguy I did not understand this part. I already amended my first block of code to the case expression twice.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you want a conditional sum:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN <condition> THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER (
    PARTITION BY pc
    ORDER BY a DESC, b DESC
) as r
```

If you want `NULL` for the non-matching values:

```
(CASE WHEN <condition>
      THEN SUM(CASE WHEN <condition> THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER (
                PARTITION BY pc
                ORDER BY a DESC, b DESC
              )
 END) as r
```

Comment: Please see my edit. If I replace 1 by rownum(), it does not start from 1 but from whatever rownum it belongs to.

Comment: @Jeiv . . . I think this basically does what you want.  However, on the rows where the value is not incremented, it just returns the previous value.  That seems consistent with the question, but not with the desired results (and it is easily fixed by wrapping this in a `case` expression).

Comment: But that does an incremental count, not just putting rownums starting from 1 where the condition is met...

Comment: @jeiv . . . This starts from `1` where the condition is met.  That is what your example does.

Comment: This will behave like `rank()`, not like `row_number()`, if there are duplicate values in the `(a, b)` composite. Not a good answer in my view.